# Does an object have to have a behavior? What if you just want to hold some info on a certain object and nothing else?

Tags: java

Does an object have to have a behavior? What if you just want to hold some info on a certain object and nothing else? Here is an example:

```
Human alice = new Human(female, 15, 5);
Human bob = new Human(male, 45, 6);
alice.eatFood(carrots, 1);
bob.rideBike(3, 4.5);
Human Class
Human(String gender, int age, int height)//constructor
eatFood(String food, int volume)//method
rideBike(int gear, double distance)//method
```

This is the code that was given to me to understand objects, but I do not see Human doing anything until it is called for the method in the Human Class. If it is not doing anything, why is it even a object? I might be missing something obvious but I can not seem to find it. Does the method count as the behavior? Or is the constructor the method that counts as a behavior since constructors are basically methods just used for holding variables. (Keep in mind that I am a very new programmer and this is the first programming language I'm learning).

Edit: An example of "doing something":

```
class StrRefExample
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    String str;

    str = new String("example string");
    System.out.println(str);
  }
}
```

Here, the "example string" is going into the class and is being made into the data type the we know as

```
String str = "example string";
```

The "being made" is the behavior and "example string" is the data. I know from that that this is an object.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967733/objects-with-state-and-behavior-in-oop

Comment: Also, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213646/is-value-object-a-bad-pattern).

Comment: How do you imagine an object "doing something" without any method being called? Give an example of an object, that "does something".

Comment: Classes with no behaviour works like `struct` in C and C++. You can Google when to use `struct` in C++.instread of using a `class`. That will answer your question.